# Calculate field tool vs Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser

I have successfully populated a field in Arc using the Field Calculator, however I would like to re-create this in python as part of a tool I am making. I was going to do this buy using 'Calculate Field' and copying the python snippet. However I can not get this to work.

This is the successful expression that works in the Field Calculator:

[image]

However, when I try the same in Calculate field I get this error:

[image]

This is how I am running it:

[image]

Comment: This could occur because of Background processing enabled in ArcMap or 64-bit GP installed (apart from other things). Google the error, there are tons of hits. Consider switching to Python and use the `'ND_' + str(!FID! + 1)` instead.

Comment: Original issue not resolved, however python suggestion by Alex Tereshenkov works perfectly fine as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

This could occur because of Background processing enabled in ArcMap or 64-bit GP installed (apart from other things).

As a quick workaround, you could use the Python parser:

```
'ND_' + str(!FID! + 1)
```